# Is the grammar of lua language ambiguous?

Tags: lua, grammar, ambiguous

I read the [lua grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/lua/Lua.g4)

I saw this [image]

see the part of "exp operatorMulDivMod exp"
or "exp operatorAddSub exp" or others

I think I can build 2 parse trees from that grammar right?
examples:
a + b + c
or
a + b * c

Comment: I don't understand your question. what is ambiguous about this?

Comment: Don't know how lua manages this specifically but default left-associativity and precedence defined by order in the list would seem to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: The [oficial grammar](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9), from which this seems to have been derived, contains this note: "For operator precedences, see §3.4.8".

Comment: This grammar, as written, is ambiguous. As others mention, there are other rules besides this grammar which allow for expressions to be interpreted unambiguously.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave are handled by associativity and precedence respectively.

But there are ambiguities in the grammar. Let's look at the following:

```lua
f()
( x or y )()
```

It could be parsed as two statements, one that calls `f` with no arguments and then calls `x` or `y` with no arguments.

But at least one compiler parses it as a single statement of three function calls.

```lua
f()( g or h )()
```

If you want the former interpretation, you can disambiguate using `;`.

```lua
f();
( x or y )()
```

The latter interpretation is far more likely to be the interpretation of one's compiler. That interpretation can be ensured using parens, although storing the intermediary results in variables might be clearest.